# Prolog : counting values in a list

Tags: list, count, prolog

I have facts with numeric attributes (letters with assigned numeric values).

```
point(a, 1).

point(b, 3).

point(c, 3).

%etc for the rest of the alphabet
```

I need to write a programme in Prolog that would count these attributes in a list. Instead, now I only managed to count elements in the list, not their attributes. Could you give me any advice? That would help me a lot !

```
count_points([ ], 0).

count_points([H|T], Count) :-
    count_points(T, Number),
    Count is Number + 1.
```

The answer should reproduce following example input/output:

```
?- count_points([h,e,l,p], Score).

    Score = 14.
```

I wrote 14, but it depends of the assigned number to the letter.

Comment: See the online help for formatting. Code excerpts are usually formatted fixed spacing by indenting each line by 4 spaces.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  It looks like you are asking for homework help.  While we have no issues with that per se, please observe these [dos and don'ts](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions/338845#338845), and edit your question accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would go with (see [here](http://swish.swi-prolog.org/p/http%3A//stackoverflow.com/questions/41965482/.pl) online):

```
point(u, 1).
point(r, 2).
point(i, 3).
point(e, 4).
point(l, 5).

count_points([], 0).
count_points([H|T], Count) :- count_points(T, N), point(H, P), Count is N + P.

% count_points([u, r, i, e, l], X).
% X = 15
```

Comment: The input would be letters, not numbers. The result should look something like this: % count_points([u,r,i,e,l], X).
% X = 15

Comment: Thank you so much! That's perfect!

Comment: @lele the other "fun" way to do this is: `count_points(Points, TotalCount) :- maplist(point, Points, Counts), sumlist(Counts, TotalCount).`

Comment: a la SQL: `count_points(Letters, Total) :- aggregate(sum(V), L^(member(L,Letters),point(L,P)), Total).`